# Can't upload images from strapi to Digital Ocean Spaces

Tags: javascript, strapi, digital-ocean-spaces

I'm trying to upload images to Digital Ocean Spaces from the Strapi admin panel to persist the media over the server restart but after sveral hours of debugging I still can't find a reason why the images are not uploading to the database.

This is my .env file:

```
DO_SPACE_ACCESS_KEY=access-key-from-spaces
DO_SPACE_SECRET_KEY=access-secret-from-spaces
DO_SPACE_ENDPOINT=ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com
DO_SPACE_BUCKET=my-bucket-name-here
DO_SPACE_DIRECTORY=/
DO_SPACE_CDN=https://my-bucket-name-here.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

And this is my config/plugins.js:

```
module.exports = ({env}) => ({
    // ...
    upload: {
      config: {
        provider: "strapi-provider-upload-do", 
        providerOptions: {
          key: env('DO_SPACE_ACCESS_KEY'),
          secret: env('DO_SPACE_SECRET_KEY'),
          endpoint: env('DO_SPACE_ENDPOINT'),
          space: env('DO_SPACE_BUCKET'),
          directory: env('DO_SPACE_DIRECTORY'),
          cdn: env('DO_SPACE_CDN'),
        }
      },
    }, 
    // ...
  })
```

Whit this configuration the image uploads to strapi media library but the image won't go to Digital Ocean Spaces. Also the url for the uploaded images are like this: `https://https//5ddca55609adfdd79f85c9c5c01c6c63.svg` when it should be the origin url to the image inside Spaces.

Is there something wrong with my configuration and what could I try to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `https://` from `DO_SPACE_CDN` value.

So your .env file become:

```
DO_SPACE_ACCESS_KEY=access-key-from-spaces
DO_SPACE_SECRET_KEY=access-secret-from-spaces
DO_SPACE_ENDPOINT=ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com
DO_SPACE_BUCKET=my-bucket-name-here
DO_SPACE_DIRECTORY=/
DO_SPACE_CDN=my-bucket-name-here.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com
```